# Rotate reminder in camera

Tags: camera

**Is there any way to have a Samsung Galaxy S3 remind the user to rotate the device when shooting video or photographs?**

The user in question keeps promising to start rotating the device when photographing but always forgets. I do understand that the problem might be the wetware and not the hardware, but I argue that the form factor and UI of the device actually encourages this behaviour.

Comment: This looks like something that would require a custom app. I'm not sure any camera app would implement something like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a job for [Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/tasker/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm):

**Profile CameraRotate:**

- *Condition:* App → Camera
- *Task:* Notify Sound (Text: "Rotate me, please!", Sound: [select file])

This way, whenever the camera app becomes the active (foreground) app, a notification will appear with the text specified. You can also include a sound (maybe something annoying or shocking, to make the "user in question" really aware). Also, instead of the notification you could chose "play sound", and have a pre-recorded MP3 played saying/shooting something like "Hey, don't forget to rotate the device!"

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great app. I'll try it on the camera and report back.

Comment: Please do! You also might wish to take a look at [other questions tagged "tasker"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tasker) and the [tasker tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) on this site for ideas and links. *Tasker* is not an app you simply install and use, it's rather complex, but definitely worth the time to learn! I'm using it for several years now, and couldn't go without it anymore :)